# Webpack minification -p errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm testing my production javascript with minifcation using webpack. It works fine unminified but when i add the `-p` flag:

```
NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -p --progress --colors
```

I get warnings and there are javascript errors. Appears it's removing things it shouldn't. Can't figure out why.

**Warnings:**

```
WARNING in client.js from UglifyJs
Side effects in initialization of unused variable React [./~/fluxible/lib/Fluxible.js:12,0]
Dropping unused function $$$enumerator$$makeSettledResult [./~/fluxible/~/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:361,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable $$utils$$now [./~/fluxible/~/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:35,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable $$utils$$o_create [./~/fluxible/~/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:38,0]
Dropping unused variable internals [./~/react-router/~/qs/lib/utils.js:6,0]
Dropping side-effect-free statement [./~/fluxible/addons/provideContext.js:6,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable Action [./~/fluxible/~/dispatchr/lib/Dispatcher.js:7,0]
Dropping unused variable internals [./~/react-router/~/qs/lib/index.js:9,0]
```

**Here's my webpack.config.js**

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');


module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './client.js',
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'assets'),
    filename: 'client.js',
    publicPath: '/assets',
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, exclude: /node_modules\/(?!react-router)/, loader: 'react-hot!babel-loader?stage=0' },
      { 
        test: /\.scss$/, 
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    // activate source maps via loader query
                    'css?sourceMap!' +
                    'sass?sourceMap'
                )
      },
      // bootstrap
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-eot',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2',
      },
      { test: /\.js$/, include: /node_modules\/bootstrap/, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
    ],
  },
};
```

Thanks

Comment: The warnings texts are self explanatory, actually. And none of them refer to your code, doesn't it?

Comment: I guess I didn't explain that well but the Warnings don't make any sense. Running webpack without the -p flag creates a client.js bundle without any errors. For instance, 'Side effects in initialization of unused variable React'... React is one of the core libraries i'm using. No idea how it's figuring that React is unused.

Comment: Those are not errors, those are warnings. Your bundle is compiled and ready to use. "No idea how it's figuring that React is unused" --- it is used, not everywhere there is a reference to it though.

Comment: So I opened one file it refers https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible/blob/master/lib/Fluxible.js#L12 The variable `React` is not used anywhere in the file, hence it might be (and is) removed. So?

Comment: In browser console error I'm getting after minification is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined`. That's the real problem. This error is referring back to a class I wrote. That's definitely defined before minification breaks my bundle.

Comment: Not sure what to make of the Warnings webpack is dumping. If they made more sense to me I prolly wouldn't be posting.

Comment: Could you post some code around that error (both: before and after minification)? "Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined" is definitely not enough to provide any meaningful advice.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I've actually got this all in a public repo https://github.com/captainill/flux-fluxible-rr . It looks like the error is being thrown here: https://github.com/captainill/flux-fluxible-rr/blob/master/app/components/Application.jsx#L41

Comment: You can see the app running with no errors on heroku https://fluxible-salad.herokuapp.com/. Thats with the client.js bundle unminified

Comment: Not sure how it supposed to work. According to https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible/blob/4a9193466e/addons%2FconnectToStores.js#L21 the third argument for `connectToStores` should be an object, not a function.

Comment: on master it's a function https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible/blob/master/addons/connectToStores.js#L18. That part is working just fine until I bundle with -p. I'm gonna leave it unminified for now just trying to prepare for later when I'll want it slimmed down.

Comment: Then I would take a debugger and debug a minified version in runtime, https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible/blob/master/addons/connectToStores.js#L44 this line in particular

Answer (score 0):

The warnings you see are due to the fact that the loader is parsing your node_module dependencies. Since the only you have excluded is whatever matches ***/node_modules/(?!react-router)/***

Instead of using the `exclude` option for module loaders, try only white listing the modules you want to load with `include`

`exclude` should be used to exclude exceptions
try to prefer `include` when possible to match the directories